# Failed to decrypt using provider 'DataProtectionConfigurationProvider'

Tags: c#, encryption, single-page-application, web.config-transform

I am trying to publish to an ftp server. I am encrypting my Web.config file using this code:

```
var exeConfigName = @"D:\Repo\mypp\WebApplication1\Web.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);
var section = config.GetSection("appSettings") as AppSettingsSection;
ConnectionStringsSection section2 = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;;
var section3 = config.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as ConfigurationSection;
if (section != null && section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) {
    // Remove encryption.
    section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
} else {
    // Encrypt the section.
    if (section != null) section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
}
if (section2 != null && section2.SectionInformation.IsProtected) {
    // Remove encryption.
    section2.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
} else {
    // Encrypt the section.
    if (section2 != null) section2.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
}
if (section3 != null && section3.SectionInformation.IsProtected) {
    // Remove encryption.
    section3.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
} else {
    //Encrypt the section
    if (section3 != null) section3.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
}
// Save the current configuration.
config.Save();
```

I get two webconfigs i.e Web.config(normal) and Web.config.cong(encrypted). When I publish only Web.config is shipped. So I manually added encrypted sections to the Web.config on server. But i get the following error:

Failed to decrypt using provider 'DataProtectionConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: Key not valid for use in specified state.

```
</runtime>
     <appSettings    configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
         <EncryptedData>//error highlighted in red
             <CipherData>
              <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAKvzpAGMd9EWXylxQjNCcdAQAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAABPSw54k9XlD+Mv/LWO9npqAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAALpLRoKXjtupmwjCJCBfEtwgAAAAO3J95kdVtev2Cvc1Chtkajg8ZNamBU7zV9EXNy4VQgoUAAAAVNrkN3oVQVy12XSbxdZVVilA/r0=</CipherValue>
```

How can I fix this. Also i do not have a release folder in my bin folder(weird). This is my first time publishing and doing encryption. Thanks